# Need help with HiDPI scaling

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr, hdpi

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on a Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon X1 with an additional 4K external monitor. Everything looks huge on both the internal and external monitors. I tried to scale both screns using `xrandr` command but I couldn't find the correct parameters and I ended up with the screens overlaping.

This is the result of the `xrandr` command

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6400 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   2560x1440     60.00*+  59.95  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     60.00    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     59.96    60.00    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
DP1 connected 3840x2160+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The commands I used are:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1.25x1.25 --panning 3200x1800
xrandr --output DP1 --pos 3200x0 --scale 1.25x1.25 --panning 4800x2700
```

Can you help please?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like no one can help on this one. Going to close it.